# for what should I use fn key by default on mac book pro

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I have `fn` key in left bottom conner of my macbook pro keyboard. For what purpose does it exist?

I understand that I can remap it to my needs, but what is its default function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It swaps the function of the function keys between the OS X function and the actual F1-F12 key. For example, pressing F1 normally will lower the brightness, but pressing fn+F1 will pass an actual F1. You can see these mappings by looking at the icon on the key itself.

This can be swapped in System Preferences → Keyboard so that fn+F1 will lower brightness and F1 will pass an actual F1.

[image]

Alternatively you can swap it by running the following Terminal command, then logging out:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState -bool true
```

Also, fn+fn is used by default to start OS X Dictation.

[image]

Perhaps the most common usage though, is using <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to get a delete key.

---

You can learn this by using help from Finder (⌘?), search for "fn" and read the article titled "Use keyboard function keys"

Comment: More generally, it’s used to get at keys that would be on an extended keyboard, that aren’t on a notebook one: Fn+cursor up/down are page up/down, and Fn+cursor left/right are home/end.